# $-p_{xx}+f(p)=0$ has a unique solution $p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In a paper I am reading they have the following as a Lemma without proof. So I am trying to prove it myself.

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following:

1. $f'(0) >0$
2. There exists $\eta$ such that $F(\eta) <0$ where $F'=f$ and $F(0)=0$.
3. If $u_0$ is the zero of $F$ with smallest nonzero absolute value, then $f(u_0) \neq 0$

If $f$ satisfies all of the above then
$$-p_{xx}+f(p)=0 $$

Has a unique solution $p(x)$ that satisfies

1. $p(x)>0$, $p(x)=p(-x)$, $p(0)=u_0$
2. $p(x)$ decays exponentially like $e^{-c|x|}$ with $c>0$.

I thought of using the implicit function theorem. But the solution $p(x)$ I am seeking has global properties. So how should I go about solving this problem?. Can anybody give some hints as to how I should proceed?.

**EDIT** The paper I am refering to is: *Grillakis, Shatah and Strauss: Stability theory of solitary waves in the presence of symmetry I, Journal of Functional analysis* 74, pp 160-197 (1987).It is very dense reading as you would expect from a research paper. But I am making progress, about half a page per week progress, but progress nonetheless. I am reading only the examples towards the end :). This is one is on page 186 btw.

Comment: what paper would that be?

Comment: I added the reference. I don't know if there is a standard way to add a reference on here. Please feel free to edit if that is the case.

Comment: seems quite an influential paper; consider later books that give versions. Often the first presentation of something is hard to read. http://books.google.com/books?id=L0GZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=Grillakis++Shatah++Strauss&source=bl&ots=_lItP-TcjX&sig=bQMB2iO29BZMWfbVfzoWf8H1v44&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1oorVNuqNuK3iwKHiYDYCA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=Grillakis%20%20Shatah%20%20Strauss&f=false   and various similar items

Comment: Try integrating the equation: $p_{xx}p_x = f(p)p_x \to \int p_{xx}p_x dx  = \int f(p) dp$ giving $p_x^2 - p_x^2(0) = 2F(p)$ and by solving for $p_x$ and then integrating again the solution can be written $\int_{p(0)}^{p(x)}\frac{dp}{\sqrt{2F(p) + p_x^2(0)}} = x$